# "relation already exists" after adding a Many2many field in odoo

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, relationship

I've defined the following two odoo ORM models:

```
class Weekday(models.Model):
    _name = 'ludwik.offers.weekday'
    name = fields.Char()

class Duration(models.Model):
    _name = 'ludwik.offers.duration'
    weekday = fields.Many2many('ludwik.offers.weekday')
```

When I try to start odoo I get the following message:

```
ProgrammingError: relation "ludwik_offers_duration_ludwik_offers_weekday_rel_ludwik_offers_" already exists
```

Also, when I change the `_name` properties in models, the problem persists (of course the relation name in the error message changes to reflect the rename), so it's not like it's just a conflict with some old relations already existing in the database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured this out. I have to say, I think this technically qualifies as a bug in Odoo.

**Summary**

The names of my models were too long. Every time you set a `_name` property longer than 16 characters you are setting yourself up to potentially experience this problem.

**Details**

When you create a `Many2many` relation, odoo setts up a new database table for this relation and then creates two database indexes for the table. Their name are as follows:

- `<model1>_<model2>_rel_<model1>_id_index`
- `<model1>_<model2>_rel_<model2>_id_index`

Where `<model1>` and `<model2>` are the `_name` property of an appropriate model. You can observe this in `_m2m_raise_or_create_relation` method of odoo's `BaseModel`.

There is however one catch. By default indetifiers in PostgreSQL (inluding index identifiers) [can not be longer than 63 characters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> The system uses no more than NAMEDATALEN-1 bytes of an identifier;
>   longer names can be written in commands, but they will be truncated.
>   By default, NAMEDATALEN is 64 so the maximum identifier length is 63
>   bytes.

Odoo doesn't take this into account. It happily generates much longer identifiers, which are then truncated by PostgreSQL. If both identifiers share the same first 63 characters (which for longer identifiers is quite likely) they will be treated by PostgreSQL as the same. That means the first index will be created, but creating the second one will result in an error, since it shares an identifier that was already used (at least according to PostgreSQL).

So what is the maximum length the `_name` property can have while avoiding the problem? It depends on how many characters are shared between the names of two models in m2m relation, but to fully avoid identifier truncation you should never use names longer than 16 characters.

Why 16? PostgreSQL identifiers can not be longer than 63 characters. In index identifiers generated by odoo there are 15 fixed characters. That leaves us with 48 characters, which have to accommodate three repetitions of model names. This in turn leaves us with 16 characters per single model name.

Another way to work around the issue would be to manually set a short relation name via `relation` attribute on the `Many2many` field.

Comment: I created [a ticket about the issue](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/2780) in Odoo's bug-tracking system.

Comment: Great work! As a workaround you can force a name for the relation name adding to the field an atribute `relation='<forced_rel_table_name>'`.

Comment: Great catch! I ran in to this problem too today, so it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see nay problem with your code. Maybe you arrived at a corner case the ORM can't handle well, as a result or experimenting several variations of the relation.

Probably trying with a freshly initialized database would work.

If you really want to keep working with the current database, you can try uninstalling you module and then reinstalling it. This should have it's database objects be dropped and then recreated.

Finally, it that doesn't work, try to manually drop the `ludwik_offers` tables in the database and the upgrade your module so that hey are re-created.

Comment: No, unfortunately even creating a fresh database didn't work. I get the same exact message when trying to install the module on a new database I just created.

Comment: Ok, I figured this out myself and posted my own answer here.