# Table name is too long odoo 13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am getting this error after adding a binary filed I remover the filed but getting the same error

Table name 'n_hesaby_subscription_manager_subscription_manager_res_users_rel' is too long

```
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: ("Table name 'n_hesaby_subscription_manager_subscription_manager_res_users_rel' is too long", None) - - -
```

does anyone know what it means, I can't find it

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/26101401/5320906

Comment: @sn thank you for replying does that mean that I need to shorten `_name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the look of the table name it's created from a many2many field between `n_hesaby_subscription_manager_subscription_manager` and `res.users` when you don't provide a name for the relation table Odoo will generate it for you `model_1_name_model_2_name_rel`.

So in your many2many definition specify a shorter name

```
    m2m_field_name = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.users', 
           relation='put_nice_table_name_here',  
           column1='put_nice_and_short_field_name_here_to', 
           column2='user_id', 
           string='You field label')
```

I'm using my phone sorry for my short answer I hope you get the idea, you can check Odoo standard modules you will find planty of examples.
Always specify the name of the relation in your many2many field is a good practice prevent unexpected behavior.

Comment: why do we need column1 and column2?

Comment: No you don't need to specify them, odoo will choose there names if you don't specify them. The only required argument is comodel_name